# How to disconnect, then reconnect from RabbitMQ using EasyNetQ?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, message-queue, easynetq

I am in a situation where I need to disconnect from RabbitMQ and reconnect using EasyNetQ. I'm doing this by disposing of IBus as described in the documentation.

https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/connecting-to-rabbitmq

"To close the connection, simply dispose the bus ... This will close the connection, channels, consumers and all other resources used by EasyNetQ."

However when I make the call to create a new bus, it is still shown as disconnected and disposed.

```
bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(connString);
bus.Dispose();
resolver.EasyNetQKernel.Release(bus);
bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(connString);
bus.Receive<Command>("CommandQueue"), Process);
```

At this point when I try to reset my consumers, I get an EasyNetQException with the message "Bus has been disposed."

Why can I not recreate the bus after disposing of it?

Comment: I'm assuming this has something to do with IBus being a singleton in EasyNetQ's IoC container?

Comment: What do you mean by 'reset your consumers'? do you create new subscriptions? Can you show your code? What IOC are you using, are you disposing your container as well?

Comment: Yes, do away with the old and create new with say, maybe a new prefetch count. I'm using ninject and tried calling resolver.EasyNetQKernel.Release(bus); after bus.Dispose(); thinking that this might allow me to recreate IBus, but it still is in the same state and will not allow me to create any new "subscriptions" with bus.Receive();

Comment: By the way, "resolver" is just an object that I use to setup my bindings and such. It exposes the Ninject kernel being used for EasyNetQ.

Comment: I haven't used Ninject, but could you try disposing and recreating your whole Ninject container instead of the bus instance? I think your container might be holding on to old references that are already disposed.

Comment: Hopefully Ninject has a way to release a particular object, since I don't want to have to resolve my other's as well.

Comment: Wiebe Tijsma, you are correct, I had to dispose of the kernel.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Ninject, but could you try disposing and recreating your whole Ninject container instead of the bus instance? I think your container might be holding on to old references that are already disposed.